# ServiceStack.Text json serializer with dynamic

Tags: c#, json, serialization, jsonserializer

I'm using **ServiceStack.Text** library to serialize dynamic generated objects (Anonymous Types)

it works like charm, but there is a situation it gives me the following error

```
Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType14`2[System.String,<>f__AnonymousType2`10[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String]]' to type '<>f__AnonymousType14`2[System.String,<>f__AnonymousType13`3[System.String,System.Int32,System.String]]'.
```

the situation is, this is a search method which searches using a keyword in deferent type of data and return result using c# dynamic as follows

```
dynamic data = new
                {
                 ResultType = "Place",
                 Data = new
                         {
                          Name = place.Name,
                          Address = place.Address,
                         }
                 };
```

another type could be like this with more or less properties in the `Data` sub type

then I add those `data` objects to List object, it works great, i can see the results in the debug,

[image]

but once i go to the serializer it gives me this error

Could you help me ..

Edit: 
I solved this problem partially by using **Dictionary** instead of **List** where i use the Key for the object type and the Value for the result row

```
var dicResult = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
....
dicResult.Add("Category", new
                                      {
                                        Foo = "bar",
                                        .....
                                      }

dicResult.Add("Place", new
                                      {
                                        FooInt = 123,
                                        .....
                                      }
```

the result something like this

```
{
    .....
    "Data": [
        {
            "Key": "Category",
            "Value": {
                "Foo": "bar",
                ....  
            }
        },
        {
            "Key": "Place",
            "Value": {
                "FooInt": 123,
                .....
             }
        }]
}
```

But i still seeking for better solution

Comment: `var s = ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(data);` works fine for me - I get `{"ResultType":"Place","Data":{"Name":"Foo","Address":"Bar"}}`; can you show how you're serializing it? Also: we can't see what `place` is, so: what is the types of `Name` and `Address` ? Are they strings? or objects? Also: does the problem go away if you use `var data = ...` instead of `dynamic` (I'm wondering if it is caching per-`T`, and of course all `dynamic` will use `T` = `object`)

Comment: @Marc i attached sample data for the results

Comment: Also i changed dynamic to var it didn't make any difference